# How to swap table name in oracle

Tags: oracle

I have 2 oracle tables that are identical in definition just different in partition definition. I want to test one table vs another table design. Is there a way to swap the table name? I don't want to drop a table because they are big and takes a long time to load data into them.

Comment: Sean - Do any of the answers work for you?

Answer (score 10):

Use a [synonym](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_7001.htm) that points to the **real** tables.

For example,

```
CREATE OR REPLACE SYNONYM partition_test FOR partition_table1;
```

Test **partition_table1**, e.g. `select pt.* from partition_test pt;`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE SYNONYM partition_test FOR partition_table2;
```

Test **partition_table2**, e.g. `select pt.* from partition_test pt;`

Notice the test code is then same each time.

When you're done testing, drop the synonym.

```
DROP SYNONYM partition_test;
```

Answer (score 3):

Just rename them.  For example, if you have TABLE_A, rename it to TABLE_A_TEMP. Then rename TABLE_B to TABLE_A. Then rename TABLE_A_TEMP to TABLE_B.

To rename, you'll have to issue

```
alter table table_name rename to new_table_name;
```

Answer (score 2):

A third method would be to use a view.  Let's say your "real" table names are TABLE_A and TABLE_B.  Create a view, MY_DATA_VIEW (or whatever), and have it point to whichever table you want it to point to:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW TEST_VIEW AS SELECT * FROM TABLE_A;
```

or

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW TEST_VIEW AS SELECT * FROM TABLE_B;
```

Share and enjoy.