# prod oracle table continues read

Tags: sql, oracle11g, oracle12c

looking for some help on one scenario.
i have one OLTP application(**app1**) which frequently reads metadata table, This table has only 2k records.
Another application(**app2**) needs to refresh(remove and insert 2k records again) metadata table few times in a day.

Since there there is no downtime how do i refresh the metadata table?

one option i can think of is:

1. Add column "ACTIVE" to metadata table(initial load put 1 as Active)
2. app1 while reading always use Active=1
3. app2: 1st insert new metadata with Active=0
4. app2: 2nd Delete Active=1
5. app2: 3rd update all rows Active=1
6. app2: finally commit

I'm not very convinced above option, is there any alternative option?

Comment: What is app3? If there is only one app that updates, as long as it does all the updating in a single transaction, you don't actually have a problem, especially since the table is tiny.

Comment: Why don't you use triggers to update your table? It would be more real time than the way you are using.

Comment: a solution is to load new data in a temporary table and once ready, swap the 2 tables. you can do that with RENAME statement or using SYNONYMS. This is the most performant approach in terms of rapidity, but will work only in certain conditions (notably same technical user, no foreign key violations). This is ideal for a datawarehouse or reporting DB, less in an intensive operational DB. See [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/177959/how-do-i-swap-tables-atomically-in-oracle) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9058809/how-to-swap-table-name-in-oracle/9060136) for ideas

Comment: @Mat, app3 was typo its actually an app2.  yes only app2 will update this table in single transaction.  my worry was on applying delete on this table few times in a day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the problem that would require downtime?  You shouldn't need to do anything special here unless, say, you have 2,000 rows of data but each row is hundreds of MB in size or you have some queries in App1 that run for several hours (which seems unlikely in an OLTP application).

So long as you do the `delete` and `insert` as part of a single transaction, which you say you are, you should cause no problems for App1.  Any queries App1 runs before the refresh commits will see the state of the data before the refresh.  Any queries App1 runs after the refresh commits will see the state of the data after the refresh.  Readers never block writers and writers never block readers in Oracle so App1 isn't going to care that App2 is in the middle of a refresh (well, it may have to do slightly more work to read the data if it needs to use the data in the `undo` segments to reconstruct a read-consistent view of the data but it's unlikely that will have a meaningful impact on performance).

Comment: Thanks Justin Cave,  was thinking of too many times DELETEs on table, but as the  table is too small(max 2k records of very less size) we should be ok i believe.